# Why am I getting a Type Mismatch when assigning a Worksheet to a Worksheet var?

Tags: worksheet, type-mismatch, aspose-cells

I am trying to incorporate Aspose Cells for .NET into this class that is using Excel Interop (rather than rewrite the whole thing to use Aspose Cells, which I am just now trying out, I want to at least start with a hybrid approach).

The problem is that I get a "Type mismatch" exception with this code:

```
private Workbook _xlBook;
. . .
Worksheet asposePT = _xlBook.Worksheets[_xlBook.Worksheets.Add()];
```

My project has a reference to Aspose.Cells, version 16.11.0.0 (Runtime version v4.0.30319)

I have these usings in the class file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ReportRunner.SharedCode;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

This is the exception detail:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  HResult=-2147352571
  Message=Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
  Source=System.Dynamic
  ErrorCode=-2147352571
  StackTrace:
       at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String 
message)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Sheets , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.PopulatePivotTableSheetAsposeCells() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner - 
Private Build\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 1550
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.GenerateProduceUsageRpt() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner - Private Build
\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 167
  InnerException: 
ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 1550 is:
Worksheet asposePT = _xlBook.Worksheets[_xlBook.Worksheets.Add()];
```

Do I need a "using Aspose" or something like that? Do I need to explicitly declare Worksheet as an Aspose Worksheet (as opposed to Excel Interop), or what?

### UPDATE

Even when I changed the code from this:

```
Worksheet asposePT = _xlBook.Worksheets[_xlBook.Worksheets.Add()];
asposePT.Name = "AsposePivotTable";
Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotTableCollection pivotTables = asposePT.PivotTables();
```

...to this (not parens are removed at end of last line):

```
Aspose.Cells.Worksheet asposePT = _xlBook.Worksheets[_xlBook.Worksheets.Add()];
asposePT.Name = "AsposePivotTable";
Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotTableCollection pivotTables = asposePT.PivotTables;
```

...I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Aspose.Cells` APIs (an independent .NET library) and MS Excel Interop (Office Automation) APIs are different in many ways, both have different architectures, so you cannot just parse objects regarding their API b/w them. I think you should use only `Aspose.Cells` APIs to instantiate a Workbook (spreadsheet), add/update or manipulate data into the worksheets, etc. and finally save the Excel file. I guess your underlying `_xlBook` object might be culprit which you might have instantiated with respect to MS Excel Interop. APIs.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.